# Tableau mapping attribute to unique identifier

Tags: mapping, tableau-api

I have downloaded a dataset of patient stay duration from Kaggle and I am trying to use Tableau to create a dashboard to understand the data better. Within the dataset there is a column labeled "stay" and it consists of a range of the number of days the patient stayed. Example, 30-40, 60-100, Nov 20th, 100+ etc. What I am trying to do is map a unique integer value to each one of these. So Nov 20th would be mapped to 1, 30-40 might be mapped to 2, etc. I can easily do this in Pandas, but I am trying to see if there is a way to do this in Tableau itself. I tried googling but all of the results come up as mapping for geographical data. Is there a way to do this in Tableau or do I have to use my Pandas solution? Here is an example of what the values look like in the csv.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First please format your data as String. I believe 20-nov should be 11-20 instead.
If you have to display the integer values instead of these ranges you can use ALIAS feature.  Right click the field/dimension and use alias
However if you have to use calculation on these integer values you can use CASE statement function